# El codigo no corre pues tiene variados errores que no sé como arreglar

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.9

en el siguiente ejercicio debo realizar un grafico de presion vs volumen molar de un gas ideal para tres temperaturas distintas (las cuales se llaman isotermas).

El primer problema es que me lo pide para un rango de 0.1 mol/l a 30 mol/l a razón de 0.1 mol/l, cosa que no sé como pedirle ya que trabajo con float.

El segundo problema es que defino una variable que contenga a los 3 rangos de presión, pero cuando quiero ingresar los parametros de los cuales depende me dice : presion() missing 2 required positional argument: 'T_3'y "R"

Por último, tengo que graficar P vs V, pero al intentarlo me dice que x e y deben tener la misma primera dimensión, pero tienen forma (50,) y (3,50), cosa que no sé cómo arreglar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Aplicación: Para 1 mol de GI graficar PV con isotermas 300K,400K y 500K.
#Generar en el gráfico una leyenda indicando las isotermas correspondientes
#Variar el volumen molar V de 0.1 mol/l a 30 m/l a razón de 0.1


#Tenemos los valores de V por los cuales debemos pasar, por ende deberíamos obtener P

vol_mol=np.linspace(0.1,30) #mol/l #no sé como pedirle que me tome un rango de 0.1 entre valor y valor
T_1=300 #K
T_2=400 #K
T_3=500 #K
R= 0.082 #l.atm/K.mol

def presion (vol_mol,T_1,T_2): #aca cuando agrego T_3 y R me dice que  presion() missing 2 required positional argument: 'T_3'y "R"
   p1=vol_mol*R*T_1
   p2=vol_mol*R*T_2
   p3=vol_mol*R*T_3
   return p1,p2,p3
p1=presion(vol_mol,T_1,R)
p2=presion(vol_mol,T_2,R)
p3=presion(vol_mol,T_3,R)

print("Las presiones para la isoterma 300K son: ",p1)
print("Las presiones para la isoterma 400K son: ",p2)
print("Las presiones para la isoterma 500K son: ",p3)

plt.plot(vol_mol,p1,color="g",label="isoterma 300 K")
plt.plot(vol_mol,p2,color="m",label="isoterma 400 K")
plt.plot(vol_mol,p3,color="r",label="isoterma 500 K")

plt.title("Isotermas")
plt.xlabel('Volumen molar')
plt.ylabel('Presión')
plt.legend(title="Isotermas")

plt.grid("darkgrid")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Es confuso. ¿Por qué tienes 3 variables llamadas p al igual que las de fuera de la función? Explica lo que quieres hacer con esos función. Por cierto, el nombre de la variable `vol_mol` no es muy descriptivo. Mejor llámala `molPorLitro`.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy claro que necesitas, y de graficar nada, osea, no debería contestar, pero bue, te dejo lo que me parece que debería ser la base de tu programa.

```
T_1 = 300 #K
T_2 = 400 #K
T_3 = 500 #K
R = 0.082 # l.atm/K.mol

def presion( T_1, T_2, T_3, R ): 

      # iteramos en el rango que nos propone el ejercicio, el duo "0.1, 30" 
      # marca los limites y el "0.1" final el tamaño del salto.  
    for vol_mol in range( 0.1, 30, 0.1 ):

          #calculamos las distintas presiones para cada volumen molar
        p1 = vol_mol * R * T_1
        p2 = vol_mol * R * T_2
        p3 = vol_mol * R * T_3

          # llamamos a graficar con los valores obtenidos
        graficar( p1, p2, p3, vol_mol )

  # acá son todas dudas, básicamente copié tu código metido en una función, pero no se
  # si funciona así
def graficar( p1, p2, p3, vol_mol ): 
    plt.plot( vol_mol, p1, color = "g", label = "isoterma 300 K" )
    plt.plot( vol_mol, p2, color = "m", label = "isoterma 400 K" )
    plt.plot( vol_mol, p3, color = "r", label = "isoterma 500 K" )
    
    plt.title( "Isotermas" )
    plt.xlabel( 'Volumen molar' )
    plt.ylabel( 'Presión' )
    plt.legend( title="Isotermas" )
    
    plt.grid( "darkgrid" )
    plt.show()


presion( vol_mol, T_1, T_2, T_3, R )
```

Los mensajes los quite porque creo que interferirían con el gráfico